# Error using @wordpress/create-block to create multiple blocks on Windows

Tags: plugin-development

I am attempting to use `@wordpress/create-block` as a starter for a plugin with multiple blocks. According to the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/#quick-start) as well as [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/25188#issuecomment-1088973599) as well as [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_4loYiEcbg), I should be able to simply copy everything in the `src` directory into a new subdirectory inside it for each block, renaming each block's name and title accordingly in its respective `block.json`, and then run `npm run build` to compile, and it should work out-of-the-box. I even tried *exactly* copying the process in the video, with the same folder names and everything.

Frustratingly, although it is successfully copying the `block.json` from each block into a matching subdirectory of `build`, it does not compile anything. So I end up with this:

```
root
-> build
    -> block-one
       -> block.json
    -> block-two
       -> block.json
-> node_modules
-> src
    -> block-one
        -> block.json
        -> edit.js
        -> editor.scss
        -> index.js
        -> save.js
        -> style.scss
    -> block-two
        -> block.json
        -> edit.js
        -> editor.scss
        -> index.js
        -> save.js
        -> style.scss
-> .editorconfig
-> .gitignore
-> plugin.php
-> package-lock.json
-> package.json
-> readme.txt
```

In my terminal, I get the following messages:

```
Skipping "./index.js" listed in "C:/path/to/plugin/src/block-a/block.json". File is located outside of the "src" directory.
No entry file discovered in the "src" directory.
asset block-a/block.json 411 bytes [emitted] [from: src/block-a/block.json] [copied]
webpack 5.75.0 compiled successfully in 16 ms
```

While searching around for solutions I came across [this pull request](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/38781) about an issue specific to Windows, however it has since been merged as it apparently fixed the issue.

So I'm not sure what to do. If you've tried this on Windows and gotten it working, did you need to change anything besides the folder structure and the name/title in `block.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much confusion I finally figured it out. `@wordpress/create-block` will not compile if the plugin is created in a symlinked directory.

See: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/45792